# How to get User JWT access_token in Authorize endpoint

Tags: c#, https, jwt, token

I want to get the user access_token inside an authorize controller to call other API with this token.
For example:

```cs
 [Authorize]
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
 public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
 {
  var token = //get actual user access_token 
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000");
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new                                     System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
  var a = httpClient.GetStringAsync("/api/messages").Result;
 }
```

I tried to get from HttpContext.User but there is no token.

Comment: It should be in the headers of the request. Look for the header with key: `Authorization`, you can access the `Headers` via `Request.Headers`

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to get the token

```cs
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public IActionResult Controller()
        {
            var token = await 
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        }
```